# Should I remove import statement from .swift file if I'm not using it?

Tags: swift, xcode

The project I'm working on has several **import** statements at the top of the .swift file...

ex.

```
import RxSwift
import Realm
import UIKit
```

If I'm not using Realm within that file, is it "bad" to `import Realm`?

When I say "bad", what I mean is...

- Will the performance of the app suffer
- is it bad practice

I can't find any documentation for this online. It's very likely that it's out there and I haven't found it yet. Any links to documentation on this topic are appreciated.

Comment: It depends on the size of your app. If you don't need to import just remove it.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @LeoDabus. I had the same thought but the project is pretty big and this appears to be a running theme throughout it, so I'm trying to figure out if there's a way to measure its impact.